# how to fix my api in kendo grid in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, kendo-grid

I want use my api in angular js by kendo,but it error me.

my code is:

```
scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "Authorization": ""
                    },
                    url: "http://localhost:35143/api/" + "Kiosks?isActive=false"
                }
            },
            sort: {
                field: "CreationTime",
                dir: "desc"
            },
            schema: {
                data: 'results',
                total: 'count',
                model: {
                    Id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "number" },
                        MobileNumber: { type: "number" },
                        CreationTime: {},
                        Description: {},
                        OrderStatus: { type: "int" },
                        IsConvertToArea: { type: "boolean" },
                        Customer: {
                            Id: {},
                            FirstName: {},
                            LastName: {},
                            EmailAddress: {},
                            IsActive: { type: "boolean" },
                            UserId: {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true

        },

    };
```

my error in console web browser is:

http://localhost:35143/api/Kiosks?isActive=false&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=5&%24orderby=CreationTime%20desc

%24 %20 is extra,how i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

These two are encoded characters. %24 means $ and %20 indicates space.

[ASCII Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Check why it is appending $ character in request parameter in your kendo grid datasource definition.

You can decode these characters by using `decodeURIComponent()` in [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp).